# Invalid Markup Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: c#, xaml, app.xaml, vs-community-edition, generic.xaml

I'm pretty new to C# and .XAML and I'm having some problems being able to see the UI for my .XAML file.

I'm getting an "Invalid Markup" error, and in the .XAML code, I get the error

*The name "DynamicBaseHostedControl" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Microsoft.crm.UnifiedServiceDesk.Dynamic;Assembly=Microsoft.Crm.UnifiedServiceDesk.Dynamics".*

The first line of code in my .XAML file is:

`USD:DynamicsBaseHostedControl x:Class="X.CTIHostedControl.CQAPhonecallInteraction"`

The error message produces a squiggly line under 
`<USD:DynamicsBaseHostedControl`.

The file is saved under C:\Users\first.last\Desktop\X.CTIHostedControl-V2\X.CTIHostedControl-V1 - Copy\X.CTIHostedControl so having a shared saving environment is not the issue. I also tried right clicking the file in the solution explorer and clicking "Clean" and restarting, but that didn't work either.

Interestingly enough, one of the files in my X.CTIHostedControl solution works and produces a UI.
The code of this first line is `<Window x:Class="X.CTIHostedControl.CallTransfer"`

To me, this implies that there is something that went wrong when using `<USD:DynamicsBaseHostedControl` vs. using `Window x:Class`

Thank you!

Comment: Does anybody have any advice?